# How can I restore my iPad from iOS 5 to iOS 4?

Tags: ios, restore

I updated my iPad from iOS 4 to iOS 5 yesterday, without making any backup. However, I  found that it is not convenient for me to debug my programs. So I want to restore it to iOS 4 again.

I did as follows:

1. Downloaded iOS 4.3.3
2. Downloaded iTunes 10.4 to replace 10.5
3. Connected iPad with my PC
4. First, I click the on/off button for seconds and then keep clicking the on/off button and home button for about 10 seconds. At last, I keep clicking the home button only for about 15 seconds. iTunes detected my iPad in restore mode.
5. Following the tips of iTunes, I clicked "Option" and "Restore" button to choose the Firmware I downloaded and tried to restore my iPad.

However, something is wrong here. The error is:

> ***this device isn't eligible for the requested build***

Can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes will not willingly load a lower iOS onto a device. Have you looked into the tiny umbrella program to see alternate methods to trick iTunes into doing what you wish.

iOS 4 requires an shsh key to sign the 4.3.3 package for your specific device. *This key normally comes from the itunes actication servers.* Unless you have already saved that key, the automation tools won't work and you'll have to do muh deeper hacking to crack this nut.

---

tl;dr

- read up on jail breaking
- it might be too late for you to go back easily

Answer (score 0):

If you see this isn't eligible for the requested build this means  that Apple has stopped signing the 4.3.3 update. Sorry.